# React Native cant display Image from object

Tags: javascript, html, xml, react-native

source={require("../assets/image1.png")} - work!!! ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
but -> source={require(image.img)} --- doesn't work (image.img = "../assets/image1.png")

```
 export default function Home({ navigation}) {
        var images = [
            {
                key: 0,
                img: "../assets/image1.png",
                user: "milos_markovic",
            }
        ]
      return (<View style={styles.slike}>
                {images.map(image => {
                    return(<View >
                        <Image
                            source={require(image.img)}


  //this doesn't work (source={require(image.img)})   , image.img = "../assets/image1.png"
  //but this -> source={require("../assets/image1.png")} work, why i cant get image from object 
     
           />
                </View>)
            })}
          </View>
  )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use require in object:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  const images = [
    {
      key: 0,
      img: require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png'),
      user: "milos_markovic",
    }
  ]
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={images[0].img}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

LIVE example https://snack.expo.dev/2qkBNGQRg